# Как в Express определить маршруты в системе CRUD?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Может вопрос поставлен не корректно, но суть такова.
Есть к примеру маршруты:

```
router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        // Просмотр какого нибудь списка
    })

router.route('/:element')
    .get((req, res) => {
        // Просмотр элемента списка
    })
    .put((req, res) => {
        // Обновление элемента списка
    })
    .delete((req, res) => {
        // Удаление элемента списка
    })

router.route('/add')
    .get((req, res) => {
        // Страница добавление элемента в список
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        // Добавление элемента в список
    })
```

Как сделать так что бы можно было указать, что маршрут такой это Update страница, маршрут такой - Delete и т.д...

Что бы по итогу получить к примеру такие данные:

```
var obj = {
    path : '/',
    create : '/add',
    read : '/:element',
    update : '/:element',
    delete : '/:element'
}
```

Находил различные пакет для Express в npm но пока только для старых версий...

Answer (score 0):

Вы это можете видеть с помощью `req.method`:

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
console.log(req.method); // GET
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я пошел другим путем, а в express такое не провернуть без ковыряния в кишках фреймворка или вспомогательного пакета для express... для таких целей нужен другой фреймворк или просто сделать по другому...